# Use passportjs authenticated tokens to send a tweet?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, passport.js

I'm using [passportjs](http://passportjs.org/) to authenticate users. Now I want to be able to send a tweet (or post on the user's facebook feed) with their permission and on their behalf. Can this be done?

Can I use a package like [twitter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter) or any other package?

From passportjs, I have clientIDs, clientSecret keys, and I assume I get back authenticated access tokens of some sort. Can these be passed to some other package to send tweets?

Comment: This article/video really helped me though it's slightly dated: https://coolaj86.com/articles/how-to-tweet-from-nodejs.html

Comment: I'm happy to accept someone else's answer if they want to take the time to write out the code. If enough people want me to do it, I'll post a concise answer